# D3 Bar Chart, bars not showing, axis on top

Tags: d3.js

I have a codepen here - https://codepen.io/ttmtsimon/pen/EbPgrw

I am trying to create a simple bar chart in D3.

The axis are showing but the x axis is on the top and it should be on the bottom and the bars are not showing at all.

I know this is a bad question but I can't see where the code is wrong, any help would be appreciated.

```
let margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom:100, left:60}
let width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right
let height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom
let x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .padding(0.5);
let y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0])

let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .tickFormat((d) => { 
    return d.x;
  });

let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)

let svg = d3.select('.barGraph')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(" + margin.left + "." + margin.top + ")');

d3.json('https://api.myjson.com/bins/vkbjf', (data)=>{
  x.domain(data.map((d)=>{
    return d.name
  }))

  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, (d)=>{
    return d.rank
  })]);

  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('tranform', 'translate(0 " + height + ")')
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll('text')
    .style('text-anchor', 'end')
    .attr('dx', '-0.5em')
    .attr('dy', '-55em')
    .attr('y', 30)
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(-45)');

  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(yAxis)
    .append('text')
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
    .attr('y', 5)
    .attr('dy', '0.8em')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
    .text('Member Rank')

  svg.selectAll('bar')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .style('fill', 'orange')
    .attr('x', (d)=>{
      return y(d.rank)
    })
    .attr('height', (d)=>{
      return height - y(d.rank)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues, namely, you don't define `width` or `y` for your rectangles. Also, the rectangle height should be equal to `y(value)` rather than `height-y(value)` (this is the top of the rectangle, and therefore the rectangle's `y` property, as svg coordinates start from the top at y=0). Your rectangle attributes should probably look more like:

```
  svg.selectAll('bar')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .style('fill', 'orange')
    .attr('x', (d)=>{
      return x(d.name)
    })
    .attr('height', (d)=>{
      return y(d.rank)
    })
    .attr("width",x.bandwidth())       
    .attr("y",(d)=>height - y(d.rank))
})
```

Second, you have inconsistent quotations in your transforms (svg and x axis appends respectively below):

```
   .attr('transform', 'translate(" + margin.left + "." + margin.top + ")');

   .attr('tranform', 'translate(0 " + height + ")')
```

Which is why these aren't being appended right, also you need commas between the two values.

Updated [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOormm).